# SSL certificate/ Streaming API on SalesForce

Tags: iphone, ssl, salesforce, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am developing a hybrid mobile app using Salesforce. I am at a point where I am dealing with Apple's Push Notification Service. In the apple's developer guide it ask that we install the SSL certificate on the provider server

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW6

How can I do that on Salesforce? Is there a tutorial somewhere that I missed. Is it even possible? I also looked into how Saleforce can communicate with the APNS and two option came up. Urban Airship and Streaming APi. Urban Airship cost money (after 1 million notifications?) so I would like to use Streaming API. Any good tutorials on how to use Streaming API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the Spring 14 release, Salesforce supports Apple ( APNS ) and Google ( GCM ) mobile push notifications via the Connected Apps framework. Please check the Mobile Push Notifications Tip Sheet on Developer Force for more information: http://www2.developerforce.com/en/mobile/resources

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with APNs, but from looking at the doc you provided, it says, "streaming TCP socket design for sending push notifications as binary content to APNs." Apex does not provide a way to make raw TCP callouts, so it doesn't sounds like this is going to work. You can [set a client cert for HTTP callouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm), but that is not going to help here.

If you want to stay in the Salesforce family, you could create a service on [Heroku](http://heroku.com) to listen for events from Salesforce and then stream them to APNs over a TCP socket. To get the events from Salesforce to Heroku (or any other external service you choose), you could use the [Streaming API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API), [Apex HTTP callouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_http.htm), or [Outbound Messaging](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm).

Comment: Oh, good timing! Today there was a [blog post](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/2/helios) about an new open source framework called [Helios](http://helios.io/) that does iOS push notifications on Heroku. Seems like it would be pretty easy to extend this to take data from Salesforce.

Comment: Ryan's first comment answer my question, but please read his second comment for a solution.